# Imitate "onselectstart=return false" using CSS or other non-JS approach?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a  button CSS class that uses background images with different positions to display a different image on normal, mouseover, and click states.
One thing completely destroying the visual effect is that if I click such a link repeatedly and move the mouse just a pixel, the link text gets selected.

Is there a way to achieve the effect of

```
onselectstart = "return false;"
```

without having to specify that for each button? A CSS based solution would be perfect, but I can't think of one. Any ideas?

One way would be iterating through each "button" element using prototype or JQuery and setting the onselectstart event manually. However I am allergic to Javascript when not absolutely necessary, and would appreciate any non-JS ideas.

**Edit:** I have found a solution for Mozilla browsers:

```
 -moz-user-select:none;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> One thing completely destroying the visual effect is that if I click such a link repeatedly and move the mouse just a pixel, the link text gets selected.

Is it really a link? Normally you cannot select link text.

If you are using eg. a div as a faux-link, perhaps you ought to use a link instead (if it goes somewhere with a real href), or an input-button if it's just for scripting (although this requires some styling to lose the browser default styles, which is a bit of a pain).

Otherwise, Safari/Chrome/Konqueror replicates Mozilla's property under its own name:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-khtml-user-select: none;
```

For other browsers you need a JavaScript solution. Note `onselectstart` returning false is only sufficient in IE and Safari/Chrome; for Mozilla and Opera one would also have to return false `onmousedown`. This may also stop the `click` firing, so you would have to do whatever script stuff you have planned for the button in the `mousedown` handler before returning false, rather than `onclick`.

You can of course assign those handlers from script, to avoid messing up the markup, eg.:

```
<div class="button">...</div>

.button { -moz-user-select: none; -webkit-user-select: none; -khtml-user-select: none; }

function returnfalse() {
    return false;
}

var divs= document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i= divs.length; i-->0;)
    div.onselectstart= returnfalse;
```

Comment: Very nice and complete. Thank you!